# how to patch one instance of argparse python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sub class that inherits and both classes make use of the argument parser module.
How can I mock a specific argument parser so that my test returns fake data for the argument parser in the base class, but not the sub class?

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self, argv):
     self.parser = ArgumentParser()
     self.args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

class Child(Parent):
     super().__init__(argv)

     def need_these_args(self):
        self.parser = ArgumentParser()
        self.args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
```

I would like the call to parser and args in `need_these_args` to return a real result, but I want to mock only the call in Parent. I am testing against class `Child`

I tried with `@patch.object(ArgumentParser, "parse_known_args", return_value=mock_arg_parse)` but that patches all calls it seems.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to restrict the scope of the patch.  `mock.patch` can be used in a `with` statement instead of as a decorator:

```py
def test_foo(self):
    with patch.object(ArgumentParser, "parse_known_args", 
                      return_value=mock_arg_parse):
        parent = Parent(argv)
    # child is outside the with statement, so it gets the original behaviour
    child = Child(argv)
```

If `argv` will be different between parent and child, another option would be to vary the behaviour based on the value of `argv`.  You can use `side_effect` instead of `return_value` to achieve this.  When you set `side_effect` to a function, it will be passed the parameters and its return value will be the return value of the patched function.

```py
parent_argv = ['a', 'b', 'c']
parent_result = 'foo'

child_argv = ['x', 'y', 'z']
child_result = 'bar'

def mock_parse_known_args(argv):
    if argv == parent_argv:
        return parent_result
    else:
        return child_result

@patch.object(ArgumentParser, "parse_known_args", 
              side_effect=mock_parse_known_args)
def test_foo(self):
   parent = Parent(parent_argv)
   child = Child(child_argv)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I'm not testing parent though, only child. So in your first approach, wouldn't the call to Child still invoke both arg parsers?

Comment: Oh, if you want `child = Child()` to have the mock and `child.need_these_args()` to have the normal behaviour, put `child = Child()` in the `with` block and `child.need_these_args()` outside the `with` block.